# Происхождение слова "поджарый"

Tags: этимология

Интересно, почему подтянутых людей называют "поджарыми"? Какая тут связь со словом "пожариться"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Этимологический словарь Фасмера:

По мнению Преобр. (II, 86), сокращено из поджа́ристый : под-жа́рить. •• [Правильнее видеть в слове поджа́рый первонач. обозначение гончего пса с подпалинами; ср. уже явно недвусмысленное название масти, а не степени упитанности ст.-польск. maść роdżаrа – о лошадях. Знач. поджарый "сухощавый, худой" явилось вторичным. См. Трубачев, Слав. названия дом. животных, стр. 26–27. – Т.] Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973**

Этимологический словарь русского языка:`
Поджарый 
Искон. Производное от *жар*. Значение «худой, сухощавый» развилось из значения «с подпалинами» (первоначально о гончей). 
*Школьный этимологический словарь русского языка. Происхождение слов. — М.: Дрофа Н. М. Шанский, Т. А. Боброва 2004***

Answer (score 2):

Поджарый - как-будто на сковороде поджаренный. Поджарка - кулинарное блюдо. Вначале более относилось к цвету/масти животных, позже так стали называть сильных и сухощавых, как бы слегка  "подсушенных" на огоньке...